# animated slider not continuing on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an animated slider that displays images and animates back and forth unless mouse is hovered, it pauses on mouse hover and needs to continue on mouse leave. I created this but having some silly issues when mouse leaves, the animation would only complete one cycle. some help.
Here is the code :

```
jQuery.fn.makeScroller = function(options){
    var defaults = {  
        hoverStop : true
    };  
    var options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

    obj = this;

    var scrollWrapWidth = 0;
    obj.children().each(function(){ scrollWrapWidth += $(this).width(); });

    scrollWrapper = jQuery('<div/>',{class:"scrollWrapper", style:"width:"+scrollWrapWidth+"px"});

    obj.children().wrapAll(scrollWrapper);
    function  animateThis(obj, dist, time){
        obj.animate({marginLeft: dist}, {
            duration:time,
            complete:function(){
                obj.animate({marginLeft: "0"}, {
                    duration:time,
                    complete:function(){
                        animateThis(obj, dist, time);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
        obj.hover(function(){
            obj.stop(true);
        }, function(){
            animateThis(obj, dist, time);
        });
    };

    widthDiff = (scrollWrapWidth - obj.width()) * -1;
    animateThis(obj.children(".scrollWrapper"), widthDiff, 3000);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    id = ".myScroller";
    jQuery(id).makeScroller();
});
```

Here is a link to the fiddle I created for you to see the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/cruising2hell/YvNR6/4/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a

```
obj.stop(true);
```

above

```
animateThis(obj, dist, time);
```

solved the problem.

```
obj.hover(function(){
        obj.stop(true);
    }, function(){
        obj.stop(true);
        animateThis(obj, dist, time);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue could be related to the fact that you are rebinding to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events (via the `hover()` method) inside of the animation-completed callback. The first time you mouse-over, one `mouseenter` event will fire, the next time two will, then three, etc. This can be shocking for performance, and cause some very odd behavour.

I would suggest moving the event binding out of there, like something along these lines:

```
obj.children().wrapAll(scrollWrapper);

function  animateThis(obj, dist, time) {
    obj.animate (
        { marginLeft: dist }, 
        {
            duration:time,
            complete:
                function() {
                    obj.animate (
                        { marginLeft: "0" }, 
                        {
                            duration:time,
                            complete:function() {
                                animateThis(obj, dist, time);
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
        }
    );
};

widthDiff = (scrollWrapWidth - obj.width()) * -1;

function resumeAnimation() {
    animateThis(obj.children(".scrollWrapper"), widthDiff, 3000);
};

resumeAnimation();

obj.hover(
        function() {
            obj.children(".scrollWrapper").stop(true, false);
        }, 
        function() {
            resumeAnimation();
        }
    );
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YvNR6/12/